# How to change Language setting in Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition

Tags: c#

I have Installed Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2008, and it is in French. I want to change the language to English.

Is it possible, please suggest solutions if any.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any particular reason to use VS 2008 Express, you may download VS 2013 Express (various editions for you to choose) [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs). You can choose any language you want before downloading. Download it, uninstall your 2008 French edition, and then install the new version you downloaded.